# Analyses of mixed variables (cart)

Tags: r, cart, mixed-type-data

I'm relatively new to statistics, and am currently working some data collected as a part of an interview survey. I have a response variable in ordinal form, which mostly looks into people's perceptions of an animal, and a range of predictor variables that include discrete numeric, ordinal and binary variables. I have a couple of questions regarding the analyses:

Would it be appropriate to use Classification and Regression trees to analyse the data? If yes, is there a limit on the number of predictor variables that can be used for sample sizes of 50 and 139 (two sets of data to be analysed separately)?

Would it make sense to use MDS or Factor analysis to reduce the number of variables?

Answer (score 0):

You have mentioned a number of analytic approaches but its hard to tell whether they are appropriate since you don't specify the objectives of your study. If your purpose is to build a model that predicts the response category that a case with a given set of predictors will fall into, then using classification trees might be appropriate. The goals of MDS and Factor analysis is to detect meaningful underlying dimensions that allow the explanation of observed similarities or dissimilarities between the investigated objects/cases. They are useful for data reduction as you suggest but you have to consider whether it is really necessary depending on the number of variables in your data (you dont give a clue) set and what use/interpretation is intended for you work.

Answer (score 0):

A solid approach to take would be to use a [lasso regression](http://statweb.stanford.edu/~tibs/lasso/simple.html).  This type of regression perform variable selection for you, so you won't need to use MDS or factor analysis before modeling.